# Giving a query to my database and returning the result

Tags: php, android, jquery, mysql, database

So I put a function in my php function code which was

```
public function getName($name){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'name' = '$name' or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

return "$result";
}

Edit: my question is how do I call this code in my android class so that I can put that result in an arraylist which is my ultimate goal.

I am trying to get all the names in that column and put them in an array list.
And so in my activity android class i put this code.

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

    User user = new User();
    user.setName(name);
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setPassword(password);

    usernames.add(name);
    ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
    request.setOperation(Constants.REGISTER_OPERATION);
    request.setUser(user);

    Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

    response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

            ServerResponse resp = response.body();
            Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
```

I am not sure if this is right, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What seems to be the actual problem? Are you not getting what you're expecting?

Comment: Sorry I'll edit the question.

Comment: Please specify the problem you are facing to be able to get help.

Comment: Well you need to make an endpoint in your web application which will receive a request with all these parameters and return a JSON result containing the data that should be displayed.

Comment: The purpose of my query is to get the values from the names column in my database table called users, is the query done right?                                                2) How do I then put the result in my android class so I can put the result in an array list. Thank you!

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.